# SQL Query For Producing User Access List to Servers

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, report

I’ve built a few tables and queries in SQL Server, but now I’m stuck as to how to make them work together in this latest task.
There’s a table, we’ll called it ServerAssessment. It has an inventory of servers, such as their Name and their Server Edition, which is Developer, Production, Unknown, etc. There’s  much larger table called DatabaseDetails that contains thousands of records regarding IDs. Each row has a Server Name, a User Name, and other details not needed here. 
The difficulty I’m having is that I need to produce a query that lists only Developer servers (WHERE Server Edition = 'Developer') but also then follows up and lists every distinct User Name (from DatabaseDetails) following it.
From a SQL logic standpoint, I am not sure how this is best completed.  It would look something like this, I would think? Or am I coming at this completely from the wrong angle?

```
ServerA001  User00001   User00002   User00003   User00111
ServerA015  User00001   User00002   User60005   User29031   User11111
ServerC037  User00001   User00009
ServerD066  User00001   User00002   User00003   User12312   User12333, User14141
ServerN123  User00001   User00003   User00009
```

Again, a user may  have access to many, many servers. Should instead of listing everything out by distinct server, instead transpose everything so it's by distinct/unique User, and then list out the servers? Would one be more ideal in a professional atmosphere?

All I have currently is something short and sweet, to join the tables and make sure only Developer is returned.

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT [Server Name]
    , [Server Edition]
FROM [ServerAssessment] AS tabDI
    FULL JOIN [DatabaseDetails] AS tabUD
        ON tabDI.[Server Name] = tabUD.[Server Name]
WHERE [SQL Server Edition] = 'Developer'
ORDER BY [Computer Name] ASC
```

PS: These were originally tables in Excel, but I imported this into SQL Server since I feel more comfortable with SQL as of my work the last few months.

Answer (score 0):

First, using a full join will give you records from details that are not directly related to developer servers.  You want to use a left join instead to get all development servers but only details related to them.

Second you will have to look up how to do a dynamic sql pivot if you want to do this in SQL.  This will cause trouble when creating a report as the number of columns will change.  I suggest you use a reporting tool that can auto-pivot for you.  I did something similar using SSRS/

Answer (score 0):

I would use ROW_NUMBER function togheter with PIVOT operator thus:

```
SELECT  *
FROM (
    SELECT /*DISTINCT*/ tabDI.[ServerName], [UserName], 
        ColNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY tabDI.[ServerName] ORDER BY [UserName])
    FROM (VALUES 
        ('ServerA001', 'Developer'),
        ('ServerA002', 'Enterprise'),
        ('ServerA015', 'Developer')
    ) AS tabDI ([ServerName], [SQL Server Edition]) -- [ServerAssessment]
    LEFT JOIN (VALUES -- LEFT JOIN for servers without users
        ('ServerA001', 'User00001'),
        ('ServerA001', 'User00002'),
        ('ServerA001', 'User00003'),
        ('ServerA001', 'User00006'),
        ('ServerA002', 'User00001'),
        ('ServerA015', 'User00003'),
        ('ServerA015', 'User00004') 
    ) AS tabUD ([ServerName], [UserName]) -- [DatabaseDetails]
    ON tabDI.[ServerName] = tabUD.[ServerName]
    WHERE [SQL Server Edition] = 'Developer'
) x
PIVOT ( MAX(x.UserName) FOR x.ColNum IN ([1], [2], [3], [4] /*, ...*/) ) y
ORDER BY y.[ServerName]
```

*Note*: This solution works for a limited number of users (4 in above case).